Speed up numpy looking for best indices
I have a numpy array that maps x-y-coordinates to the appropriate z-coordinates. For this I use a 2D array that represents x and y as its axes and contains the corresponding z values:
import numpy as np
x_size = 2000
y_size = 2500
z_size = 400
rng = np.random.default_rng(123)
z_coordinates = np.linspace(0, z_size, y_size) + rng.laplace(0, 1, (x_size, y_size))

So each of the 2000*2500 x-y-points is assigned a z-value (float between 0 and 400). Now I want to look up for each integer z and integer x which is the closest y-value, essentially creating a map that is of shape (x_size, z_size) and holds the best y-values.
The simplest approach is creating an empty array of target shape and iterating over each z value:
y_coordinates = np.empty((x_size, z_size), dtype=np.uint16)
for i in range(z_size):
    y_coordinates[:, i] = np.argmin(
        np.abs(z_coordinates - i),
        axis=1,
    )

however this takes about 11 s on my machine, which unfortunately is way to slow.
Surely using a more vectorised approach would be faster, such as:
y_coordinates = np.argmin(
    np.abs(
        z_coordinates[..., np.newaxis] - np.arange(z_size)
    ),
    axis=1,
)

Surprisingly this runs about 60% slower than the version above (tested at 1/10th size, since at full size this uses excessive memory).
Also wrapping the code blocks in functions and decorating them with numba's @jit(nopython=True) doesn't help.
How can I speed up the calculation?

You could potentially reduce the search space for each argmin by considering only the entries that "round" to the integer of interest. In other words, you could use a mask of the form z_coordinates.round() == i

@BenGrossmann I like the sound of that, but I'm unsure how to code it. Could you please elaborate?

I'll see what I can put together if I find the time. The tricky part is that applying a mask messes with the indexing for the argmin

There's no good way to vectorize my method using numpy, it would seem, and when I coded it with for loops my approach took about 40% longer than yours

@YPOC: I have just added a solution that, on my machine, completes within 0.4s.

@BenGrossmann I think the algorithm in my answer is similar to your approach though it does not directly use z_coordinates.round(). Maybe it can be optimized further with rounding rather than the current array accesses and comparisons. I tried to just use rounding, but results was wrong. I might have missed something or maybe this needs some corrections like in my answer... Such approach can make things up to twice faster (the optimal time to read/write the input/output is 6 ms on my machine).

This answer provide an algorithm with an optimal complexity: O(x_size * (y_size + z_size)). This algorithm is the fastest one proposed so far (by a large margin). It is implemented in Numba using multiple threads.

Explanation of the approach
The idea is that there is no need to iterate over all Z values : we can iterate over z_coordinates line by line, and for each line of z_coordinates, we fill an array used to find the nearest value for each possible z. The best candidate for the value z is stored in arr[z].
In practice, there are tricky corner cases making things a more complicated. For example, due to rounding, I decided to fill the neighbours of arr[z] (i.e. arr[z-1] and arr[z+1]) so to make the algorithm simpler. Moreover, when there are not enough values so arr cannot be fully filled by all the values in a line of z_coordinates, we need to fill the holes in the arr. In some more complicated cases (combining rounding issue while kind of holes in arr), we need to correct the values in arr (or operate on more distant neighbours which is not efficient). The number of step in the correction function should always be a small constant, certainly <= 3 (it nerver reached 3 in practice in my tests). Note that, in practice, no corner case happens on the specific input dataset provided.
Each line is computed in parallel using multiple threads. I assume the array is not too small (to avoid to deal with more corner cases in the code and make it simpler) which should not be an issue. I also assume there are no special values like NaN in z_coordinates.

Resulting code
Here is the final code:
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

# Fill the missing values in the value-array if there is not enough values (e.g. pretty large z_size)
# (untested)
@nb.njit('(float64[::1], uint16[::1], int64)')
def fill_missing_values(all_val, all_pos, z_size):
    i = 0
    while i < z_size:
        # If there is a missing value
        if all_pos[i] == 0xFFFF:
            j = i
            while j < z_size and all_pos[j] == 0xFFFF:
                j += 1
            if i == 0:
                # Fill the hole based on 1 value (lower bound)
                assert j+1 < z_size and all_pos[j] == 0xFFFF and all_pos[j] != 0xFFFF
                for i2 in range(i, j):
                    all_val[i2] = all_val[j+1]
                    all_pos[i2] = all_pos[j+1]
            elif j == z_size:
                # Fill the hole based on 1 value (upper bound)
                assert i-1 >= 0 and all_pos[i-1] != 0xFFFF and all_pos[i] == 0xFFFF
                for i2 in range(i, j):
                    all_val[i2] = all_val[i-1]
                    all_pos[i2] = all_pos[i-1]
            else:
                assert i-1 >= 0 and j < z_size and all_pos[i-1] != 0xFFFF and all_pos[j] != 0xFFFF
                lower_val = all_val[i-1]
                lower_pos = all_pos[i-1]
                upper_val = all_val[j]
                upper_pos = all_pos[j]
                # Fill the hole based on 2 values
                for i2 in range(i, j):
                    if np.abs(lower_val - i2) < np.abs(upper_val - i2):
                        all_val[i2] = lower_val
                        all_pos[i2] = lower_pos
                    else:
                        all_val[i2] = upper_val
                        all_pos[i2] = upper_pos
            i = j
        i += 1

# Correct values in very pathological cases where z_size is big so there are not enough 
# values added to the value-array causing some values of the value-array to be incorrect.
# The number of `while` iteration should be always <= 3 in practice
@nb.njit('(float64[::1], uint16[::1], int64)')
def correct_values(all_val, all_pos, z_size):
    while True:
        stop = True
        for i in range(0, z_size-1):
            current = np.abs(all_val[i] - i)
            if np.abs(all_val[i+1] - i) < current:
                all_val[i] = all_val[i+1]
                all_pos[i] = all_pos[i+1]
                stop = False
        for i in range(1, z_size):
            current = np.abs(all_val[i] - i)
            if np.abs(all_val[i-1] - i) < current:
                all_val[i] = all_val[i-1]
                all_pos[i] = all_pos[i-1]
                stop = False
        if stop:
            break

@nb.njit('(float64[:,::1], int64)', parallel=True)
def compute_fastest(z_coordinates, z_size):
    x_size, y_size = z_coordinates.shape
    assert y_size >= 2 and z_size >= 2
    y_coordinates = np.empty((x_size, z_size), dtype=np.uint16)
    for x in nb.prange(x_size):
        all_pos = np.full(z_size, 0xFFFF, dtype=np.uint16)
        all_val = np.full(z_size, np.inf, dtype=np.float64)
        for y in range(0, y_size):
            val = z_coordinates[x, y]
            #assert not np.isnan(val)
            if val < 0: # Lower bound
                i = 0
                if np.abs(val - i) < np.abs(all_val[i] - i):
                    all_val[i] = val
                    all_pos[i] = y
            elif val >= z_size: # Upper bound
                i = z_size - 1
                if np.abs(val - i) < np.abs(all_val[i] - i):
                    all_val[i] = val
                    all_pos[i] = y
            else: # Inside the array of values
                offset = np.int32(val)
                for i in range(max(offset-1, 0), min(offset+2, z_size)):
                    if np.abs(val - i) < np.abs(all_val[i] - i):
                        all_val[i] = val
                        all_pos[i] = y
        fill_missing_values(all_val, all_pos, z_size)
        correct_values(all_val, all_pos, z_size)
        for i in range(0, z_size):
            y_coordinates[x, i] = all_pos[i]
    return y_coordinates


Performance results
Here are performance results on my machine with a i5-9600KF CPU (6 cores), Numpy 1.24.3, Numba 58.1, on Windows, for the provided input:
Naive fully vectorized code in the question:   113000 ms  (slow due to swapping)
Naive loop in the question:                      8460 ms
ZLi's implementation:                            1964 ms
Naive Numba parallel code with loops:             402 ms
PaulS' implementation:                            262 ms
This Numba code:                                   12 ms  <----------

Note the fully-vectorized code in the question use so much memory it cause memory swapping. It completely saturate my 32 GiB of RAM (about 24 GiB was available in practice) which is clearly not reasonable!
Note the PaulS' implementation is about equally fast with 32-bit and 64-bit on my machine. This is probably because the operation is compute-bound on my machine (dependent of the speed of the RAM).
This Numba implementation is 705 times faster than the fastest implementation in the question. It is also 22 times faster than the best answer so far! It also use a tiny amount of additional RAM for the computation (<1 MiB).

Hi Jérôme, your method looks very promising and indeed runs lightning fast. Could you please explain what compute_loops() is for? You don't use it anywhere in your code.

@YPOC compute_loops is another independent implementation. It is the "Naive Numba parallel code with loops" implementation (which is basically your Numpy version but using basic loops and multiple threads). I removed it to make the code simpler.

Thank you Jérôme. I went through your code and fixed a little bug in fill_missing_values()

@YPOC Thank you for the improvement and sorry for the bug. I carefully tested compute_fastest, checked a bit correct_values, but not much fill_missing_values (only on 2-3 basic cases) so I trust your changes ;) . Note that assertions are not raised when parallel=True is set (this is an issue of Numba -- at least the version 0.58.1). You need to disable parallelism parallel=False so for assertions to be raised properly (only needed for debugging purposes).

for some reason on my machine using a for loop is faster than vectorization:
for j in range(x_size):
    y_coordinates[j, i] = np.argmin(np.abs(z_coordinates[j, :] - i))

Not sure what is the reason behind this.
However, if this is how you actually generate the z_coordinates, I believe you can speed it up by eliminating unlikely choices of y as for each y, z is likely to be distributed within a small range:
y_coordinates_new = np.empty((x_size, z_size), dtype=np.uint16)
m_min = np.min(z_coordinates, axis = 0)[:, np.newaxis] - np.arange(z_size)
m_max = np.max(z_coordinates, axis = 0)[:, np.newaxis] - np.arange(z_size)
m_range_min = (m_min*m_max > 0) * np.minimum(np.abs(m_min), np.abs(m_max))
m_range_max = np.maximum(np.abs(m_min), np.abs(m_max))

for i in range(z_size):
    candidates = np.where(m_range_min[:, i] <= np.min(m_range_max[:, i]))[0]
    y_coordinates_new[:, i] = candidates[np.argmin(
       np.abs(z_coordinates[:, candidates] - i),
       axis=1,
    )]

On my machine this is 16x faster for your example. Obviously it would be slower if you increase the variance of your random part.

Explained:
The idea is that your samples (z) are sparse by y, meaning that z values are distributed within 2500 relatively small "buckets". So to find the point closest to i, we don't need to check all the buckets as the point we are looking for would likely only exist in a few candidate buckets.
First we calculate what is the minimum distance and maximum distance to each i, within each bucket:
# min and max (z-i) in each bucket
m_min = np.min(z_coordinates, axis = 0)[:, np.newaxis] - np.arange(z_size)
m_max = np.max(z_coordinates, axis = 0)[:, np.newaxis] - np.arange(z_size)

# min and max possible distance to i in each bucket
m_range_min = (m_min*m_max > 0) * np.minimum(np.abs(m_min), np.abs(m_max))
m_range_max = np.maximum(np.abs(m_min), np.abs(m_max))

The minimum distance is a rough estimate for speed, if i is between the min z value and max z value in each bucket, I just assume minimum possible distance to i is 0. You could probably do better here by finding the closest value to 0.
Now, for each of these buckets, we know what is the minimum/maximum possible distance to i. We can say that given two buckets a, b, and respectively min and max distance [d1_a, d2_a], [d1_b, d2_b], we can rule out b in favor of a if d1_b > d2_a. This is the case where all points in bucket b would be further away from i compared to any points in a.
With this idea in mind, our candidates, defined as buckets where it is not strictly "worse" than any of our buckets, can be find via:
np.where(m_range_min[:, i] <= np.min(m_range_max[:, i]))[0]

Think of it this way, if d1 (the min distance) is larger than any d2 (the max distance) of any other bucket we have, there is no reason to keep this bucket.
This method is somewhat a math hack, what is nice about it is that you can combine with what other people mentioned here, like numba, presort, etc. Presort is a good idea, as there is really no point to search multiple times through the same array. We could do it further by maintaining some search index to only increase it when doing the loop, but I am afraid that might be slower than numpy's vectorization without some careful implementation.

Interestingly manually looping over both indices takes 157% longer for me than just the z index, however this is where numba really shines and it runs in just 27% of time of the original implementation.

Your implementation with checking for candidates really is super fast, and indeed my actual measured z_coordinates are fairly similar. I'm happy it was worth adding that detail in my question. Could you please explain your method a bit more? I don't really understand what each step does.

Hi @YPOC, please see the latest edit for explanation

IMPROVEMENT 1
The following approach completes the task in approximately 0.4 seconds on my machine. The key idea is to avoid using np.argmin and instead leverage binary search (np.searchsorted) on a pre-sorted array of z-coordinates.
This approach avoids the inefficiency of repeatedly using np.argmin by pre-sorting the z-coordinates for each x and then employing np.searchsorted to efficiently find the closest z-values. By sorting the z-coordinates with a complexity of O(N log N) and using binary search for each integer z, which has a complexity of O(log N), the method significantly reduces computational load compared to the original approach. This strategy involves finding the insertion point for each integer z in the sorted z-coordinates and comparing it with its neighbors to determine the closest z-value. This eliminates the need for redundant calculations and ensures that only necessary comparisons are made, thereby improving performance.
x_size = 2000
y_size = 2500
z_size = 400
rng = np.random.default_rng(123)

z_coordinates = np.linspace(0, z_size, y_size) + rng.laplace(0, 1, (x_size, y_size))

# Sort the z_coordinates for each x and get sorted indices
idx_sorted = np.argsort(z_coordinates, axis=1)
z_sorted = np.take_along_axis(z_coordinates, idx_sorted, axis=1)

zs = np.arange(z_size, dtype=np.float64)

y_coordinates = np.empty((x_size, z_size), dtype=np.uint16)

for x in range(x_size):
    positions = np.searchsorted(z_sorted[x, :], zs)
    positions = np.clip(positions, 1, y_size - 1)
    z_prev = z_sorted[x, positions - 1]
    z_curr = z_sorted[x, positions]
    diffs_prev = np.abs(z_prev - zs)
    diffs_curr = np.abs(z_curr - zs)
    closest = np.where(diffs_prev < diffs_curr, positions - 1, positions)
    y_coordinates[x, :] = idx_sorted[x, closest]


IMPROVEMENT 2
One way of improving performance is to add the following line of code:
z_coordinates = z_coordinates.astype(np.float32).copy(order='C')

Ensuring a C-contiguous memory layout and using float32 instead of float64 significantly speeds up computation by optimizing memory access patterns and reducing data size.

C-contiguous arrays store elements in a row-major order, improving cache efficiency and enabling vectorized operations by minimizing cache misses and leveraging CPU optimizations.

Switching to float32 halves memory usage, reducing memory bandwidth demands and allowing more data to fit into the CPU cache, which is especially beneficial for large arrays.


These changes align the data with the CPU's expectations, enabling faster and more efficient processing, which in your case approximately halves the execution time. The primary improvement comes from using float32 instead of float64, significantly reducing memory usage and enhancing performance.

I'm a little surprised that .copy(order='C') makes a difference - the example OP gives generates z_coordinates in C order, and astype() ought to preserve that if no order is specified. .copy() seems unnecessary here.

Thanks, @NickODell, for your comment. I have just checked that most of the performance enhancement comes from using float32 instead of float64. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Hi @PaulS, since you already implemented the idea of prev and cur positions, why not take it one step further to memorize the index for each x and remove the searchsorted part? I think this is the fastest approach in theory, neglecting the implementation differences.

Thanks, @ZLi, for your idea. I am not sure I have understood that correctly, but I suspect that the room now left to optimize the code is very narrow.

@PaulS agreed, searchsorted is probably the best with its internal vectorization

I cannot reproduce the benefit of 32-bit floats on my machine (on the code "improvement 1"). It might be because the operation is only compute bound and unaffected by the cache (quite surprising). z_coordinates cannot fit in my L3 cache anyway (20 MiB is pretty big). Same for z_sorted (which should also take 20 MiB). Maybe it is bound by Numpy overheads... How fast is the first implementation with 32-bit floats on your machine compared to 64-bit floats?

Thanks, @JérômeRichard, for your comment. My second improvement does not impact significantly when coupled with the first improvement: It approximately halves the execution time of the initial code of the OP.  In short, it was designed to improve performance of the OP's initial code (the one that uses a for loop).

Ok, thank you for the clarification. One more note on FP32: I just found out (while trying to find another more efficient approach) that using 32-bit floats results in a different output (including on the code of the OP). I do not know if the result can be considered wrong or not though...

Thanks, @JérômeRichard, for your comment.  Yes  that may happen, since the precision of the float numbers will be lower. So, the usability of FP32 depends on the required level of precision. For instance, if it is enough to work with numbers with up a few decimal digits, the FP32 is usable.

The closest-y is ambiguous. For example, if 2 values are equal, then argmin will return the first index it sees. Which might not be desirable.
With contour lines you can disambiguate these cases. For that, there is contourpy.
import contourpy as cp
z_contour_gen = cp.contour_generator(z=z_coordinates, name="threaded", chunk_count=5)

creates a contour generator which uses all threads. Then call
[z_contour_gen.lines(level=i) for i in range(z_size)] # or multi_lines

and this gave a ~30% speed up for me, and more information on z.
